# Adding exceptions for update

Tags: updates

I have installed Opera browser but an older version. Because, the most recent version does not play Netflix and some more platforms videos. This issue is related with `libffmpeg.so` file and WidevineCDM. However, I solved this issue using an older version of Opera. Now, I want an exception for Opera. I want it to be *not* updated when I enter the command `sudo apt-get update`. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: The browser is traditionally a great vector for system compromise. That's why they continually get security updates. As nice as it sounds to just keep an older browser installed, maybe a better solution would be to working on a way to play those files *even if it means temporarily using an alternative browser* until Opera fixes this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, one of the easiest way is you can mark hold on those packages.
e.g:

> apt-mark hold vim